# How to wait for a IScheduler.Schedule?

Tags: c#, system.reactive

What is the best way to wait for something scheduled on a `IScheduler`, i.e is there any elegant way to get a future or IObservable the schedule call?

```
scheduler.Schedule(() => Thread.Sleep(2000));
// wait for call to finish
```

Answer (score 1):

Solved it with `Observable.Start().FirstOrDefault()`